# postgresql ignore milliseconds from timestamp when doing a select statement

Tags: postgresql

I have TableA and it has a field of
 time_captured  | timestamp without time zone | default now()
It is being used to record when data was inserted into the table. However, I am trying to do a select and ignore milliseconds.
So instead of having

```
2015-07-11 18:06:33.690498
2015-07-12 13:36:21.274509
2015-07-12 13:36:24.222577
2015-07-12 13:36:26.515593
```

I would like to have

```
2015-07-11 18:06:33
2015-07-12 13:36:21
2015-07-12 13:36:24
2015-07-12 13:36:26
```

Having the microseconds in the table is needed but what I do not need is for the output to show the microseconds.
How can I do this ?
The closest I have come is by using the following but I am not able to figure out how to pull the full date with the time as shown above.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_captured  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') FROM server_perf;   date_part
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the date_trunc function to achieve this:

```
select date_trunc('second', time_captured) from server_perf;
```

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC for more on this.